Confusion over vector notation in regression paper
I'm confused about the notation I've seen occasionally in some econ papers. Here is an example,
$Y_i=\alpha_0+\alpha_1 G_i+\alpha_2 G_i\times H_i+\alpha_3 A_i+\alpha_4 M_i+ \alpha_5 H_i+\gamma_{s(i)}+\epsilon_i$
Where $Y_i$ is the outcome of interest for student $i$, and $G_i, A_i, H_i$, and $M_i$ are binary indicator functions.
The author then says,
"I include a full vector of dummies, $\mathbf{\gamma}_{s(i)}$ in the regression."
How can $\gamma_{s(i)}$ be a vector when everything is scalar-valued? My guess is that they mean $\gamma_{s(t)}$ is really a sum of indicator functions. Is this right? And is this a common abuse of notation and terminology in math econ?

Please consider consulting our posts about dummy-coding variables for regression.  They will help clarify the sense in which any categorical feature with three or more classes cannot be represented as a scalar but requires a vector (of length one less than the number of classes provided the regression includes an intercept).

Apologies, I'm afraid I'm still not understanding. I may not understand the terminology correctly. I take it that dummy variable means an indicator function, and vector means an element of $\mathbb{R}^n$ for some $n$. In that case, how does one add a vector-valued quantity to a scalar-valued one? What does $\gamma_{s(i)}+\epsilon_i$ mean here, if $\epsilon_i$ is a normally distributed random variable? They aren't in the same vector space.  I just wanted to clarify my question, Apologies if I just repeated myself.

Please look at the referenced threads, which explain that coding a dummy variable requires multiple indicator functions--that is, a vector.  It's unclear what you mean by "not in the same vector space," because every quantity in this equation is a number (although $\epsilon_i$ is a random number...).  I suspect what might be tripping you up is a notational shorthand in which "$\gamma_{s(i)}$" refers to a collection ("vector") of parameters, one for each of the indicator variables.

That the author says $\gamma_{s(i)}$ is a vector is confusing to me. I interpret that to mean, for each fixed $i$, $\gamma_{s(i)}$ is an element of $\mathbb{R}^n$, so I don't know what it would mean to add $\epsilon_i$ to such a thing, since you can only add elements of the same vector space together. If $\epsilon_i$ was a random vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$, I could see how that might make sense. But I don't see how everything on the right is a number if the author says one of the terms is a vector. I will continue looking through the question thread though and see if it makes sense

I am reading "$\gamma_{s(i)}$" as shorthand for $\gamma_{1,i}+\gamma_{2,i}+\cdots+\gamma_{k,i}.$  It's an abominable shorthand but it's about the only reasonable interpretation of the characterization of it as parameters of the dummy variables.

Yes, that's what I also thought, if you mean $\gamma_{s(i)}$ is an indicator for each $s$. I thought the author actually meant the sum of indicators, as opposed to putting them together in a vector. I guess they could just dot it with the constant 1 vector to be precise, if I'm understanding you correctly.
